# Does changing the culture of a threadpool thread affect it when it gets returned back to the pool?

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, currentculture

If I set the `CurrentCulture` of a thread pool thread, what happens when the thread finishes execution and gets returned back to the thread pool? Does it get its `CurrentCulture` reset back to the default (whatever that may mean), or will it retain the culture I have set on it?

I'm hoping that the framework resets the thread to a default state to guard against this, but cannot find any documentation to this effect. The closest I have found is from the MSDN docs for [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx):

> When the thread pool reuses a thread,
>   it does not clear the data in thread
>   local storage or in fields that are
>   marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute
>   attribute. Therefore, data that is
>   placed in thread local storage by one
>   method can be exposed to any other
>   method that is executed by the same
>   thread pool thread.

This seems to indicate that the thread is **not** reset when it is returned.

I have tried some sample code to try to test this, and it *does* seem that the culture is reset, but I am not convinced that I am testing this behaviour correctly as I think I am only using a small subset of the ThreadPool's threads, and so cannot be sure I'm testing a thread that has already had it's culture set.

Comment: Slightly related, but mainly for reference: http://twitter.com/#!/Wintellectuals/status/27733481381

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would not rely on the ThreadPool **ever** resetting information, specifically because of the text you quoted.

If you are worried about "changing" the thread pool's culture, I would make sure to reset it when your threaded task is complete.  This is a simple enough task.

I do not believe the current threadpool does this, but even if it **did**, it would not be safe to assume that .NET 4+'s ThreadPool implementation will not change.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question really. I'm not doing this, but came across a situation whereby a new thread runs in a different culture than the main thread (as is the specified behaviour). I was curious to know what happens, as it would be easy to forget to set the culture back once the thread is done.

Comment: When the ThreadPool creates new threads, they'll use the culture of the AppDomain containing the thread.  Changing it does, btw, persist - but you never know if you're going to "reuse" that thread, and the threadpool does retire threads, so it's pretty much causing undefined, unpredictable behavior.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - In this case, how can I find the "culture of the AppDomain". I can find reference to a Thread's culture, but not the AppDomain.  The reason I ask is I am using the System.Threading.Task API to create background tasks and I believe the default implementation uses ThreadPool. The threads that are spawned seem to have the default system culture, rather than any cultures I've set on parent threads. I wanted a way to set the default culture for the entire app, but I've not found a way to do this.

Comment: @Anderson: I'd store your main thread culture, and pass it to the Task instances as needed.  Most tasks, since they're background operations, don't really worry about culture anyways - so it should be a rare thing to require.  Any task scheduled on the UI will automatically pick up the UI culture...

Comment: @Reed Copsey: Yeah, I've been passing them through closures at the moment. Your mention of an "AppDomain culture" was hopeful to me; that's what I was looking for, but it doesn't seem like that's actually a feature. In a WPF app, there are times when I need to fetch data off the UI thread. Frequently this data is meant for display, but its translation information is stored in the datastore, so I need to pass the right culture along with the query on that background thread. I agree that if I was using culture to pull resources, etc, I'd just do it on the UI thread at the presentation layer.

Comment: @Anderson: Typically, in cases like you're describing, I do the translation in the UI thread, and pass the culture-mapped data into the processing backend/datastore.  It tends to avoid the issue entirely.  (I want to do this because it makes handling improperly formatted data easier - it's already on the right thread, and those routines are fast...)