# Why *not* change the priority of a ThreadPool (or Task) thread?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, task, threadpool, thread-priority

There are many places across the web and Stack Overflow where one is discouraged from changing the priority of a **ThreadPool** thread or TPL **Task**. In particular:

["You have no control over the state and priority of a thread pool thread."

"The runtime manages the thread pool. You have no control over the scheduling of the thread, nor can you change the thread's priority."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647332.aspx)

["You should not change the Culture or Priority or... of a PoolThread. Just like you don't paint or re-decorate a rental car."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467194/does-changing-the-culture-of-a-threadpool-thread-affect-it-when-it-gets-returned)

["There are several scenarios in which it is appropriate to create and manage your own threads instead of using thread pool threads: (such as...) You require a thread to have a particular priority."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y.aspx)

["Each thread in ThreadPool runs at the default priority and the code to change the ThreadPriority has no effect."](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.general/browse_thread/thread/a19ccff5b99411c7/d7c6d0bedfa1f331)

However, it is a simple matter to do so, and the debugger shows that the change *does* seem to stick (insofar as the value can be read back).

```
Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
```

So the question is, what is the specific **reason** for this particular taboo?

My suspicion: doing so disturbs the delicate load balancing-assumptions of the pool. But this doesn't explain why some sources say that you **can't** change it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The thread pool, especially the .NET 4.0 thread pool, has many tricks up its sleeve and is a rather complicated system.  Add in tasks and task schedulers and work stealing and all sorts of other things and the reality is you don't know what is going on.  The thread pool may notice that your task is waiting on I/O and decide to schedule something quick on your task or suspend your thread to run something of higher priority.  Your thread may somehow be a dependency for a higher-priority thread (that you may or may not be aware of) and end up causing a deadlock.  Your thread may die in some abnormal way and be unable to restore priority.

If you have a long-running task such that you think it would be best that your thread have a lower priority then the thread pool probably isn't for you.  While the algorithms have been improved in .NET 4.0, it is still best used for short-lived tasks where the cost of creating a new thread is disproportional to the length of the task.  If your task runs for more than a second or two the cost of creating a new thread is insignificant (although management might be annoying).

Answer (score 9):

I've done some experimentation with a reduced-size thread pool which seems to indicate that the thread's priority is reset back to normal once returned to the pool. [This](http://www.albahari.com/threading/#_Thread_Pooling) resource on threading seems to confirm it. So the effect seems to be very limited even if you do.

Answer (score 2):

Lowering the priority could also lead to unexpected consequences.

Imagine you schedule a task in an application, but also call into a library that schedules several other tasks. Say you lower the thread priority while the app task runs. You could then end up with the normal priority tasks in the lib waiting for that low priority task to finish, if the pool doesn't spawn many threads, but the low priority thread it may not be given much CPU time if the rest of the system has many normal priority threads that want to run.

Increasing the number of pool threads would alleviate this, at the cost of wasting more memory on stacks and spending more CPU time on context switches.

Answer (score 0):

You certainly *can* change it if you really want to, but given that the thread pool threads are re-used, the next code that runs might not expect the change.

Comment: I should have mentioned that you could restore the original priority when you're done with the thread or task...

Comment: @Glenn: It's simply *not meant to be changed*. There's no CLR police to handcuff you if you do, but it's considered bad practice because thread pools are not meant to have an identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you do change anything, use try/finally to make sure you leave it as you found it.

Comment: Not helpful. Question is about WHY or WHY NOT.

Comment: @Adam - I disagree that this is unhelpful.  The reasons are covered in other answers, but if after considering the trade-offs someone decides to go ahead and to it, then reverting to the original state in a finally block so that it happens even in the event of an exception is good practice, and may easily be forgotten.

Comment: Check out Michael's answer. It points out a great thread pool resource that states "You are free to change the priority of a pooled thread — it will be restored to normal when released back to the pool."

Comment: @Adam - interesting, but it would be nice to see official documentaiton confirming it before relying on it.  Otherwise you'd have to consider it as an implementation detail that can't be relied upon.  And what about other attributes of the thread such as culture?  I still maintain that restoring state in a finally block is good practice in the absence of official documentation saying it's unnecessary.

Comment: I agree this is unhelplful because of the below answer - that is, even if you do modify it, it doesn't stick. As soon as it goes back to the thread pool it's reset. It appears the ThreadPool protects itself from this type of meddling, so try/finally is just adding a performance burden with no improved result.

Comment: @Joe: try/finally is not the correct way to manage this in the context of .NET TaskFactory Tasks. (Managing your own Threads directly is another matter.) Imagine your Task calls a library function that, for whatever reason, uses a `Wait()` or a `Sleep()` somewhere... when execution returns to your Task's code it may well be a completely different Thread from the Thread Pool and your original Thread is off being used by another Task. For example, [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12246045/390122]

Answer (score 0):

It's discouraged, specially if you're upping the priority, because it can affect the overall performance of your system.

Not to offer an overcomplicated answer, but in general, thread priority is a complex topic. For example, Windows has 2 related descriptors: thread priority and process priority. Both range from Idle, the lowest, to Time critical, the highest. When you start a new process, it's set to the default, the mid-range (a normal process priority with a normal thread priority).

Plus, thread priorities are relative, meaning that even setting a thread's priority to the highest in a busy system won't ensure that it will run in 'real-time'. DotNET offers no guarantees on this, neither does Windows. From that you can see why it's better to leave the threadpool alone, since, 99.9% of the time, it knows best :)

All that said, it's ok to lower a thread's priority if the task involves a long computation. This won't affect other processes.

Increasing priority, however, should only be done for tasks that need to react quickly, and have a short execution time, because this can negatively affect other processes.